# MongoDB - userAdminAnyDatabase can't create users

Tags: mongodb

Currently I've got a `siteUserAdmin` authenticated on the `admin` database:

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.siteUserAdmin",
    "user" : "siteUserAdmin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "credentials" : {
        "MONGODB-CR" : "...."
    },
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run:

```
use admin;
db.auth('siteUserAdmin', 'supersecret');
```

Everything authenticates just fine.

**However** when I then do:

```
use myotherdb
db.addUser({ user: 'chris', pwd: 'anothersecretpassword', roles: ['dbOwner']});
```

It doesn't add the user, I get the following:

```
couldn't add user: not authorized for insert on admin.system.users at src/mongo/shell/db.js:128
```

**What am I doing wrong? This all looks nuts.**

---

*FYIL* I'm using MongoDB version 2.6.10.

*Random side note:* weirdly `createUser` isn't a function, even though according to the MongoDB docs it was added in 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this exact error in Robomongo 0.8.5.  I copy/pasted the command to the the Mongo cli client and it worked fine.

Authenticated as siteUserAdmin to admin db on both clients.

Hopefully this helps someone else.